# Laravel can't save polymorphic relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I want to have a polymorphic relation between services and different types of service data (In this example its typo3_data).

I have the following data model:

```
projects
--------
id
name

services
--------
id
type
project_id
data_type
data_id

typo3_data
--------
id
url
```

The projects and services have a simple OneToMany Relation.  But the service model needs a polymorphic relation because there are different kinds of services which needs different columns in there respective table.

My Service Model looks like this:

```
class Service extends Model
{
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }

    public function data()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('data');
    }
}
```

The TYPO3Data Model looks like this:

```
class TYPO3Data extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'typo3_data';

    public function service()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Service::class, 'data');
    }
}
```

Currently I try to save the data on the service this way(simplified):

```
public function store(Project $project)
{
    $service = new Service(['type' => 'TYPO3']);
    $service->data()->save(new TYPO3Data(['url' => 'http://example.com']));
    $project->services()->save($service);
}
```

But now I get an error with a NOT NULL constraint on services.data_type.

Does anyone know how to solve this part, that I can save the polymorphic relation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

`save()` is meant for `HasMany` relationships. Use `associate()` instead:

```
$data = TYPO3Data::create(['url' => 'http://example.com']);
$service = new Service(['type' => 'TYPO3']);
$service->data()->associate($data);
$project->services()->save($service);
```

Also, take a look at [many-to-many polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

Comment: I tried this and I got the exact same error with either `save` or `associate`

Comment: @SpencerWilliams Please open a new question.

Comment: Thanks @JonasStaudenmeir , It worked. BTW, Your "Has Many Deep" package is awesome too. Thank you!